# Django clean password 'ValidationError' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, django

I am using django-custom-user to make login with e-mail. I have 2 models CustomUser and ClientData:

**models.py**

```
class CustomUser(AbstractEmailUser):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True, default=None)

class ClientData(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser)
    company = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    bank_account = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
```

I am trying to make a register form with both models and i have managed to do that, i have also made a clean password function, everything works, but when i purposely give 2 different password i get:

```
'ValidationError' object has no attribute 'get'
```

**forms.py**

```
class UserRegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True, max_length=150)
    first_name = forms.CharField(required=True, max_length=100)
    last_name = forms.CharField(required=True, max_length=100)
    password1 = forms.CharField(required=True, label='Password', max_length=100, widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    password2 = forms.CharField(required=True, label='Confirm Password', max_length=100, widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    phone = forms.CharField(required=True, max_length=20)

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ['email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'password1', 'password2', 'phone']

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(UserRegistrationForm, self).clean()
        password1 = cleaned_data.get('password1')
        password2 = cleaned_data.get('password2')
        if password1 != password2:
            return forms.ValidationError('Password did not match.')
        return cleaned_data

class UserDataRegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = ClientData
        fields = ['company', 'bank_account']
```

and this is the view i've made:

**views.py**

```
def register(request):
    data = dict()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)
        data_form = UserDataRegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if user_form.is_valid() * data_form.is_valid():
            cd_user = user_form.cleaned_data
            cd_data = data_form.cleaned_data
            first_name = cd_user['first_name']
            last_name = cd_user['last_name']
            email = cd_user['email']
            password = cd_user['password1']
            phone = cd_user['phone']
            company = cd_data['company']
            bank_account = cd_data['bank_account']
            new_user = CustomUser.objects.create_user(email, password)
            ClientData.objects.create(user=new_user, company=company,  bank_account=bank_account)
            new_user.first_name = first_name
            new_user.last_name = last_name
            new_user.phone = phone
            new_user.company = company
            new_user.bank_account = bank_account
            new_user.save()
    else:
        user_form = UserRegistrationForm()
        data_form = UserDataRegistrationForm()
    data['user_form'] = user_form
    data['data_form'] = data_form
    return render(request, 'registration/register.html', data)
```

Why am i getting this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't return validation errors, you should raise them.

```
if password1 != password2:
    raise forms.ValidationError('Password did not match.')
```